# Getting index of an String value within an array of array

Tags: ios

I have an unique scenario of getting **index** value of an element, where the structure is

Array - within Array - within Dictionary

```
(
    {
        STS = OPEN;
        "STS_ICON" = "LIGHT_GREY";
    },
    "Headerquarter Planning"
),
    (
        {
        STS = INPR;
        "STS_ICON" = "LIGHT_BLUE";
    },
    "In Process"
),
    (
            {
        STS = COMP;
        "STS_ICON" = "LIGHT_GREEN";
    },
    Released
),
    (
            {
        STS = CANC;
        "STS_ICON" = "LIGHT_RED";
    },
    "ON HOLD - Call Transfer Delay"
 )
)
```

iN THIS Case let's say i want **index** of @"ON HOLD - Call Transfer Delay" string.

I tried with like this..

```
NSUInteger index;
if([listOfStatus containsObject: list.statusType])
{
    index = [listOfStatus indexOfObject: list.statusType];
}
```

where list.statusType is @"ON HOLD - Call Transfer Delay". But here i am getting "index" some weird value 15744929.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
- (NSInteger)findIndexOfStatus:(NSString *)status
{

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Status"
                                                        ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSArray *listOfStatus = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:nil];


    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSArray *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {

        //NSDictionary *dict = evaluatedObject[0];
        //return [dict[@"STS"] isEqualToString:status];

        NSString *statusType = evaluatedObject[1];
        return [statusType isEqualToString:status];

    }];

    return [listOfStatus indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [predicate evaluateWithObject:obj];
    }];
}
```

You can find the index by calling

```
NSInteger index = [self findIndexOfStatus:@"ON HOLD - Call Transfer Delay"];
```

I have also commented out an option to find out if you want to use the status code.

The [Status.json](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/General/Status.json) file

Comment: what is d need of using filePath here.. and also this is not a JSON response.. the text i put is shows my DATA-STRUCTURE..

Comment: @ibiren I created a json file added to the bundle, to see if the code is working. Shared the .json file so that you can verify it.

Comment: ok.. but its giving index value as : 2147483647 #dats d problem #Thanks for ur response

Comment: @ibiren When i used with the json file I shared, I got an index of 3.

Comment: maybe.. but since i am having data already in an ARRAY(listOfStatus).. so i am not using JSON file. but i am getting index value as : 2147483647 #dats what i wonder..

Comment: @ibiren I have formed the json from the format your specified in the question. An array of arrays, with inner arrays having two values, one a dictionary and one a string. Can you step through the code. And see if everything is ok.